# Sharepoint 2010 - Start a workflow on receipt of email. Access email's body

Tags: workflow, incoming-email

I am pretty new to SharePoint. We have below scenario;
There is a list Lst1. In this list there is column Approved. Through my code am sending an email to Approver to take an action. The requirement is that from within the email user will click Approve / Reject button. User will also provide his/her comment for the action. Click of Approve / Reject button should not open browser. It may open a new email window where user can enter his here comment.

To achieve this requirement i have thought of using mailto: entity of html and provide record id and approve / reject flag in the anchor tag text like below

```
<a href="mailto:abc@def.com?subject=Test%20MailTo%20#123#&body=Approved#123" target="_top">Approve</a>
```

Here #123 is the ID of the record.

Next requirement is of starting workflow on receipt of email. for this i found below link;

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4607.sharepoint-2010-workflows-on-incoming-emails-in-sharepoint-documents-library.aspx

However i need to access the received email body / subject to know the record id and approved / rejected action.

Kindly let know how this can be done OR a better way to achieve this requirement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Following below link had configured incoming email
[Click here](https://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/configuring-sharepoint-2010-to-accept-incoming-emails/comment-page-3/#comment-7201)
Then have followed the code mentioned in [this](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/creating-a-simple-email-receiver-for-a-document-library/) link to access email content.